# How to leave a squad?

Tags: star-wars-commander

My son (who is a little too young for online gaming but has enjoyed playing SW Commander on his own for some time) has somehow joined a squad and he's receiving messages from his squadmates. I would like for him to be able to play the game but **not** be in a squad/be online. When we hit "Leave," however, it just tells us we can't leave during a Squad War. How can I exit the squad?

Answer (score 1):

The [official help page](https://help.starwars.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/How-do-I-create-a-Squad-in-STAR-WARS-Commander?section=Star-Wars) states:

> To leave a Squad:
>
> 1. Tap the Squad icon on the far right of the base screen.
> 2. Select the Overview tab
> 3. Tap Leave, then confirm

However, if you keep having this error, try to write a message to the squad leader, and ask him/her to remove your son's player from the squad.

Answer (score 0):

He can leave after the squad war is over. Apart from that I see no danger in messages there. If you think your son is old enough to play the game, join another squad. Normally there is not much chattering there.

For myself: I decided that my son was too young and that the game was too addictive. So I convinced him to uninstall the game and put a password protection on the Google Play App.

If he wants a new game we talk about it, I test the game on my smartphone and if it is not too brutal/addictive I install the game on his smartphone.